# ajax call method sharing question

Tags: javascript, ajax, methods

I have this conceptual question about ajax that I'm not sure if I understand. Say I have a page called `original` and in `original`, I use ajax to load another page into `orignal` called `ajaxPage`. My question is if `original` defined a javascript method called `testing()`, then can `ajaxPage` use `testing()`?

To me, it seems that `ajaxPage` should be able to use `testing()` because after `ajaxPage` becomes part of the `original` page, there is nothing stopping it from having a reference to `testing()`. But this also means that when coding the `ajaxPage`, you have a reference to `testing()` but with just the `ajaxPage` itself, there is no `testing()` method defined.

Does anyone have any insight as to what should happen? and why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any script loaded into the DOM, whether by AJAX or other means, will have access to code already loaded.  See demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/uCg75/2/

And yes, if you were to load the AJAX content into any context in which `testing()` is not defined (since it is not defined within itself) you would get an error for reference to undefined function.